# Python3.6 AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I tried to read https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434.
It's about asynchronous python and I tried the code from this, but I'm getting a weird Error.
The code is:
`

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yandex.ru', 'http://www.python.org']

async def call_url(url):
    print('Starting {}'.format(url))
    response = await aiohttp.ClientSession().get(url)
    data = await response.text()
    print('{}: {} bytes: {}'.format(url, len(data), data))
    return data

futures = [call_url(url) for url in urls]

asyncio.run(asyncio.wait(futures))
```

When I try to run it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    asyncio.run(asyncio.wait(futures))
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'call_url' was never awaited
```

I dont have any files named ayncio and I have proof:

```
>>> asyncio
<module 'asyncio' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) is a Python 3.7 addition. In 3.5-3.6, your example is roughly equivalent to:

```
import asyncio

futures = [...]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(futures))
```

Comment: When you grab the existing event loop, I'd not close it.. `asyncio.run()` only closes the loop because it actually creates a new loop to start with.

Comment: You might want to use `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait` to actually consume the futures and handle exceptions.

Comment: When I try this I can't actually access the content of futures on subsequent lines. I just get that `print(str(futures))` is `[<coroutine object myfun at 0x123123123>]` and, seemingly, that's that. How do I actually get the output of the function that I'm calling inside of futures?

Answer (score 56):

The `asyncio.run()` function was added in Python 3.7. From the [`asyncio.run()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run):

> New in version 3.7: **Important**: this function has been added to asyncio in Python 3.7 on a provisional basis.

Note the [*provisional* part](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-provisional-api); the Python maintainers forsee that the function may need further tweaking and updating, so the API may change in future Python versions.

At any rate, you can't use it on Python 3.6. You'll have to upgrade or implement your own.

A very simple approximation would be to use [`loop.run_until_complete()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete):

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

although this ignores handling remaining tasks that may still be running. See the [`asyncio.runners` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/asyncio/runners.py) for the complete `asyncio.run()` implementation.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case this is useful to someone else but for me the issue was my file was called `asyncio.py`. I renamed it to `asyncio_example.py` and it started to work again (it was failing at the import statement for asyncio).

This issue helped me realize this: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2868

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This solved my issue too.

Comment: I named my module "socket.py" and had ssme issue

Comment: this just save me!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having a problem with no current loop try:

```py
loop = asyncio.**new**_event_loop()

result = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```