# yield from wasn't used with future

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm running the following, using [requests-threads](https://github.com/requests/requests-threads):

```
def perform_requests():
    prepared_requests = [...]
    session = AsyncSession(n=100)
    results = []

    async def _perform_requests():
        for request in prepared_requests:
            results.append(session.request(**request))
        for i, result in enumerate(results):
            results[i] = await asyncio.ensure_future(results[i])

    session.run(_perform_requests)
    return results
```

However when I run it a couple of odd things happen, firstly I get loads of messages like:

```
(WARNING) Connection pool is full, discarding connection:
```

And secondly I get this error:

```
results[i] = await asyncio.ensure_future(results[i])
builtins.AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

I'm using `ensure_future()`, so what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session.request()` method returns a twisted `Deferred` object (the `requests-threads` code [calls `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread()`](https://github.com/requests/requests-threads/blob/b4d4384da96b09a98c97abb07b38caa72f5404cf/requests_threads.py#L56)). You generally *don't* want to treat this as an asyncio task, not and run under the Twisted reactor.

Instead, you could use [`twisted.internet.deferred.gatherResults()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#gatherResults) to execute the requests concurrently and to gather the responses.

Next, `session.run()` calls [`twisted.internet.task.react()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#react), which will *always exit Python*:

> [...] this function will also:
>
> [...]
>
> - **Exit the application when done**, with exit code 0 in case of success and 1 in case of failure.

(bold emphasis mine).

This means that even if your code works, the `return results` line is never reached.

If you move out the `session.run()` call to be the top-level entry point for your application then things work:

```
from requests_threads import AsyncSession
from twisted.internet import defer

session = AsyncSession(n=100)

async def perform_requests():
    prepared_requests = [...]
    requests = [session.request(**request) for request in prepared_requests]
    responses = await defer.gatherResults(requests)
    print(responses)        

session.run(perform_requests)
```

but does exit immediately after printing the `responses` list.

Otherwise, you'll have to manage the twisted reactor directly (using [`reactor.run()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#run) and a callback that calls [`reactor.stop()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#stop) once the responses are done); e.g.:

```
from requests_threads import AsyncSession
from twisted.internet import defer, error, reactor

def perform_requests():
    prepared_requests = [...]
    session = AsyncSession(n=100)
    results = []

    async def gather_responses():
        requests = [session.request(**request) for request in prepared_requests]
        results[:] = await defer.gatherResults(requests)
        try:
            reactor.stop()
        except error.ReactorNotRunning:
            pass

    deferred = defer.ensureDeferred(gather_responses())
    reactor.run()
    return results

print(perform_requests())
```

If you need to run multiple tasks on the twisted reactor, you'd either a single top-level function and rely on callbacks to let you know when responses are complete.

Personally, I think you'd be much better off using the [`aiohttp.client` module](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client.html#aiohttp-client) to run asynchronous requests under the Python `asyncio` event loop:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def perform_requests():
    prepared_requests = [...]
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)

    with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        requests = [session.request(**request) for request in prepared_requests]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*requests)

        print(responses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(perform_requests())
```

Note that `asyncio.run()` requires Python 3.7 or newer; your error message suggests you are still using 3.5 or 3.6. A [work-around would be to use `loop.run_until_complete()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796630/python3-6-attributeerror-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-run/52796715#52796715):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(perform_requests())
```