# asyncio run until complete not forever

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio

Could anyone give me a tip on how to run asyncio script to stop when complete? I know its something to do with how I am setting the main loop to run... in this portion of the complete code but what ever I try from what I can find online it doesnt work.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(firstWorker())
    asyncio.ensure_future(secondWorker())
    loop.run_forever()
```

The script below is just something made up attempting to compile randon data into a pandas dataframe when the script completes but I cant get it to complete! Any tips greatly appreciated...

complete code:

```
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random


data = []

async def firstWorker():
    for _ in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        things = {}

        stamp = datetime.now()

        temperature1 = (random.random() * 20) - 5
        print(temperature1)

        things['Date'] = stamp
        things['temperature1'] = temperature1

        data.append(things)



async def secondWorker():
    for _ in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        stuff = {}

        stamp = datetime.now()

        temperature2 = (random.random() * 40) - 15
        print(temperature2)

        stuff['Date'] = stamp
        stuff['temperature2'] = temperature2


        data.append(stuff)



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(firstWorker())
    asyncio.ensure_future(secondWorker())
    loop.run_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()


    master_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    master_data.columns = ['Date','temperature1','temperature2']

    master_data.to_csv('master_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `asyncio.gather` and `run_until_complete`

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(firstWorker(), secondWorker())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: If you care about the order of results you may want to use `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377319/combine-awaitables-like-promise-all

Comment: If you are using python >= 3.7 you can simplify the last 3 lines to `asyncio.run(main())`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52796630/python3-6-attributeerror-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-run

Comment: Using asyncio.wait like this makes exceptions pass silently. Use asyncio.gather instead.

Comment: In the main loop, `async def main():
    await asyncio.gather([firstWorker(), secondWorker()])` If I use `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait` this will throw an exception..

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncioRand.py", line 51, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "asyncioRand.py", line 48, in main
    await asyncio.gather([firstWorker(), secondWorker()])
  File "C:\Users\benb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 718, in gather
    if arg not in arg_to_fut:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: `gather` takes multiple arguments, `wait` takes a list. If you want to use `gather`, you need `asyncio.gather(firstWorker(), secondWorker())`