# Need to read 10 urls at a time to speed up scraping in python. urls stored in csv file

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm scraping company names from each url that are stored in csv file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import csv

with open("urls.csv", "r") as f_urls, open("results.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['url', 'results'])

    for url in f_urls:
        url = url.strip()
        html = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")           
        Company_Name = soup.find('h1')
        csv_output.writerow([url, Company_Name])
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there something you are having trouble with related to multi-threading? Please be more specific.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  - Also, the contents of your post should include some explanation of what you are trying to do along with your input data

Comment: By the way, only one thread/process can write out to the file handle at once, so your code will be blocking on it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well `html = requests.get(url).content` is something that is the 'heavy' part of your code. It downloads the website. In order to speed your code up you want to download multiple websites simultaneous.

Look into `asyncio` or this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392029/47351